# Gerund or infinitive form

Tags: infinitives, passive-voice, gerunds, sentence-structure

Which sentences are grammatically correct? Can we rewrite these sentences better?

> 1. The biggest fear people have is (that) not being approved (of).
> 2. The biggest fear people have is (that) not to be approved (of).

---

> 3. Elderly people have a desire to feel needed.
> 4. Elderly people have a desire to feel to be needed.
> 5. Elderly people have a desire to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The following versions sound correct to my (American) ear:

> 1a.  The biggest fear people have is not being approved [for a credit card].
>
> 1b.  The biggest fear people have is not being approved of.
>
> 3 .  Elderly people have a desire to feel needed.
>
> 5 .  Elderly people have a desire to be needed.

The following versions sound more natural to me:

> 1e. The biggest fear people have is that they will not be approved [for a credit card].
>
> 1f. The biggest fear people have is that they won't measure up [to society's standards].
>
> 3b. Elderly people want to feel needed.
>
> 5b. Elderly people want to be needed.

Notice that there is a difference in meaning between "approved" and "approved of".  "Approved" implies "approved for <something>" like membership in a group, or permission to do something (like borrow money on a credit card).  "Approved of" means "appreciated", "valued", or "loved".

Many people fear not being approved for a loan (such as a credit card), but it would be very strange for a person's biggest fear to be "not being approved for a credit card".  I can imagine a sit-com (like *Seinfeld*) showing a neurotic character whose biggest fear is "not being approved for a credit card".

A common phrase in English is "fear of <plural noun>" or "fear of <gerund>".  For example, "A person with acrophobia has a fear of heights", "She is afraid of cats", and "fear of flying".

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the rule that why we cannot say the second sentence?